Efficiently remove rows from pandas df based on second latest time in column
I have a pandas Dataframe that looks similar to this:



Index
ID
time_1
time_2




0
101
2024-06-20 14:32:22
2024-06-20 14:10:31


1
101
2024-06-20 15:21:31
2024-06-20 14:32:22


2
101
2024-06-20 15:21:31
2024-06-20 15:21:31


3
102
2024-06-20 16:26:51
2024-06-20 15:21:31


4
102
2024-06-20 16:26:51
2024-06-20 16:56:24


5
103
2024-06-20 20:05:44
2024-06-20 21:17:35


6
103
2024-06-20 22:41:22
2024-06-20 22:21:31


7
103
2024-06-20 23:11:56
2024-06-20 23:01:31



For each ID in my df I want to take the second latest time_1 (if it exists). I then want to compare this time with the timestamps in time_2 and remove all rows from my df where time_2 is earlier than this time.
My expected output would be:



Index
ID
time_1
time_2




1
101
2024-06-20 15:21:31
2024-06-20 14:32:22


2
101
2024-06-20 15:21:31
2024-06-20 15:21:31


3
102
2024-06-20 16:26:51
2024-06-20 15:21:31


4
102
2024-06-20 16:26:51
2024-06-20 16:56:24


7
103
2024-06-20 23:11:56
2024-06-20 23:01:31



This problem is above my pandas level. I asked ChatGPT and this is the solution I got which in principle does what I want:
import pandas as pd

ids = [101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103]
time_1 = ['2024-06-20 14:32:22', '2024-06-20 15:21:31', '2024-06-20 15:21:31', '2024-06-20 16:26:51', '2024-06-20 16:26:51', '2024-06-20 20:05:44', '2024-06-20 22:41:22', '2024-06-20 23:11:56']
time_2 = ['2024-06-20 14:10:31', '2024-06-20 14:32:22', '2024-06-20 15:21:31', '2024-06-20 15:21:31', '2024-06-20 16:56:24', '2024-06-20 21:17:35', '2024-06-20 22:21:31', '2024-06-20 23:01:31']


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ids,
    'time_1': pd.to_datetime(time_1),
    'time_2': pd.to_datetime(time_2)
})

grouped = df.groupby('id')['time_1']
mask = pd.Series(False, index=df.index)

for id_value, group in df.groupby('id'):
    # Remove duplicates and sort timestamps
    unique_sorted_times = group['time_1'].drop_duplicates().sort_values()

    # Check if there's more than one unique time
    if len(unique_sorted_times) > 1:
        # Select the second last time
        second_last_time = unique_sorted_times.iloc[-2]
        # Update the mask for rows with time_2 greater than or equal to the second last time_1
        mask |= (df['id'] == id_value) & (df['time_2'] >= second_last_time)
    else:
        # If there's only one unique time, keep the row(s)
        mask |= (df['id'] == id_value)

filtered_data = df[mask]

My issue with this solution is the for-loop. This seems rather inefficient and my real data is quite large. And also I am curious if there is a better, more efficient solution for this.

Please do not use id as variable name as it's already assigned.

Would never do that in real world but I thought for an example it wouldn't matter. But of corse you are right!

I added to your data an example with a single index

@rpanai The second latest time for id=103 is 22:41:22. And I want to remove all rows where time_2 for this id is earlier than this timestamp, which are rows 5 and 6. And your filter suggestion is ok.

@rpanai Please don't change the example data; it might change the problem.

It was according to description. We didn't have an example with a single element within a group. The author agreed with it.

@rpanai I don't see where Frede agreed with it, but if they want to add it back, by all means. In the meantime, if you want to include it in an answer, that's fine, as a way of demonstrating your assumptions about the problem.

@wjandrea why you switched back? The new data was working  perfectly for the example.

@rpanai Because, like I said, it might change the problem

It didn't change the problem and it was consistent with author description.

@rpanai Like I said, if they want to add it back, that's fine, but please don't put words in their mouth.

Worth noting that grouped is unused in ChatGPT's code.

@Frede just to be explicit, you keep rows 3 and 4 since there is no second to last date?

@mozway yes that is correct. I know it looks strange. The reason is that I am using this to clean data and in cases where there is only one time_1 the data is fine.

@wjandrea I upvoted the additional data entry because it is consistent with my problem and indeed a good additional case to test.

@Frede Oh, votes aren't public

You can use .transform() to create the mask.
Sorting is not necessary when you can just use .nlargest() and select the second one if it exists. Or if time_1 is already sorted, you can even skip .nlargest() (or sorting) entirely.
Then you just need to replace NaT with the smallest possible Timestamp value so that time_2 can't be earlier than it when you do the comparison.
second_last_times = df.groupby('id')['time_1'].transform(
    lambda s: s.drop_duplicates().nlargest(2).iloc[1:].squeeze())
mask = second_last_times.fillna(pd.Timestamp.min).le(df['time_2'])
df[mask]

Result:
    id              time_1              time_2
1  101 2024-06-20 15:21:31 2024-06-20 14:32:22
2  101 2024-06-20 15:21:31 2024-06-20 15:21:31
3  102 2024-06-20 16:26:51 2024-06-20 15:21:31
4  102 2024-06-20 16:26:51 2024-06-20 16:56:24
7  103 2024-06-20 23:11:56 2024-06-20 23:01:31

For reference, second_last_times:
0   2024-06-20 14:32:22
1   2024-06-20 14:32:22
2   2024-06-20 14:32:22
3                   NaT
4                   NaT
5   2024-06-20 22:41:22
6   2024-06-20 22:41:22
7   2024-06-20 22:41:22
Name: time_1, dtype: datetime64[ns]

If you want to generalize this, replace .nlargest(2).iloc[1:] with .nlargest(n).iloc[n-1:].

P.S. This is similar to mozway's solution, but I actually wrote the code before they posted, except the squeeze technique - thanks for that.

IIUC, you could use groupby.transform with drop_duplicates to remove the duplicates values, and .iloc[-2:-1].squeeze() to get the second to last if any, else NaT. Then perform boolean indexing:
out = df.loc[df.sort_values(by='time_1') # optional, if not already sorted
               .groupby('id')['time_1']
               .transform(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().iloc[-2:-1].squeeze())
               .fillna(pd.Timestamp(0))
               .le(df['time_2'])
            ]

Output:
    id              time_1              time_2
1  101 2024-06-20 15:21:31 2024-06-20 14:32:22
2  101 2024-06-20 15:21:31 2024-06-20 15:21:31
3  102 2024-06-20 16:26:51 2024-06-20 15:21:31
4  102 2024-06-20 16:26:51 2024-06-20 16:56:24
7  103 2024-06-20 23:11:56 2024-06-20 23:01:31

Intermediates:
    id              time_1              time_2           transform              fillna
0  101 2024-06-20 14:32:22 2024-06-20 14:10:31 2024-06-20 14:32:22 2024-06-20 14:32:22
1  101 2024-06-20 15:21:31 2024-06-20 14:32:22 2024-06-20 14:32:22 2024-06-20 14:32:22
2  101 2024-06-20 15:21:31 2024-06-20 15:21:31 2024-06-20 14:32:22 2024-06-20 14:32:22
3  102 2024-06-20 16:26:51 2024-06-20 15:21:31                 NaT 1970-01-01 00:00:00
4  102 2024-06-20 16:26:51 2024-06-20 16:56:24                 NaT 1970-01-01 00:00:00
5  103 2024-06-20 20:05:44 2024-06-20 21:17:35 2024-06-20 22:41:22 2024-06-20 22:41:22
6  103 2024-06-20 22:41:22 2024-06-20 22:21:31 2024-06-20 22:41:22 2024-06-20 22:41:22
7  103 2024-06-20 23:11:56 2024-06-20 23:01:31 2024-06-20 22:41:22 2024-06-20 22:41:22


I got something similar :) You should use pd.Timestamp.min instead of pd.Timestamp(0) in case of dates before the Unix epoch.

Would it be more efficient to sort per-group? That's my feeling, but I'm not sure why. Although, in my answer, I used .nlargest() to avoid having to sort.

@wjandrea Yes it would. If you assume n log n as the time complexity and think of 100 examples with 10 groups of 10, what changes is the the log n part. log 10 is smaller than log 100 so sorting group-wise would be slightly faster.

@wjandrea it depends on the exact data, I believe it would not necessarily. Calling sort_values multiple times also adds a non negligible overhead and python sorting is O(n*logn) on average, but is might be close to O(n) if the data is already almost sorted. Regarding the pd.Timestamp(0) this is a good remark, you could actually also fillna(df['time_1']).

@mozway I see. You mean fillna(df['time_2']), right? Then you'd be comparing those time_2 values against themselves (so that they satisfy .le to themselves).

Yes time_2, indeed, to self-compare.

Here is a possible solution using groupby
I added an example with a single element within a group
import pandas as pd

ids = [101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 104]
time_1 = [
    '2024-06-20 14:32:22', '2024-06-20 15:21:31', '2024-06-20 15:21:31',
    '2024-06-20 16:26:51', '2024-06-20 16:26:51', '2024-06-20 20:05:44',
    '2024-06-20 22:41:22', '2024-06-20 23:11:56', '2024-06-20 23:11:56']
time_2 = [
    '2024-06-20 14:10:31', '2024-06-20 14:32:22', '2024-06-20 15:21:31',
    '2024-06-20 15:21:31', '2024-06-20 16:56:24', '2024-06-20 21:17:35',
    '2024-06-20 22:21:31', '2024-06-20 23:01:31', '2024-06-20 23:01:31']


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ids,
    'time_1': pd.to_datetime(time_1),
    'time_2': pd.to_datetime(time_2)
})

We define a function that takes in account the logic within a group
def fun(x):
    if len(x) > 1:
        unique_times = x['time_1'].unique()
        if len(unique_times) >= 2:
            second_last_time = unique_times[-2]
        else:
            second_last_time = unique_times[0]
        x = x[x['time_2'].ge(second_last_time)]
    return x

df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: fun(x)).reset_index(drop=True)

    id              time_1              time_2
0  101 2024-06-20 15:21:31 2024-06-20 14:32:22
1  101 2024-06-20 15:21:31 2024-06-20 15:21:31
2  102 2024-06-20 16:26:51 2024-06-20 16:56:24
3  103 2024-06-20 23:11:56 2024-06-20 23:01:31
4  104 2024-06-20 23:11:56 2024-06-20 23:01:31

With this approach, you can see benefit if your df is getting bigger. With a 90,000 row dataframe, I saw a 25% improvement.

lambda x: fun(x) can be simplified to just fun. (BTW this is called eta-reduction)

OP's expected output preserves the index. IDK if it's significant or just for demonstration, but either way, you can preserve it too by removing the reset_index and doing df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(fun)

id=102 should have two rows. It looks like if not len(unique_times) >= 2, you should return x instead of doing second_last_time = unique_times[0].

On that note, you could use guard statements to make this code a lot cleaner: first, if len(x) < 2: return x then if len(unique_times) < 2: return x, then the rest is on the top level of the function, and IMO you don't need to reassign x, just do return x[x['time_2'].ge(second_last_time)]

BTW, you could use a better name than x, like say, group

@rpanai I like that you are using apply because in my opinion it makes code more readable. But as wjandrea pointed out your code removes row 3 which is not what I need. In cases where there is only one time_1 for an ID, all rows for that ID shall be kept.
